# React Google Recaptcha `executeRecaptcha` function always return `null` instead of returning token

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am using `react-google-recaptcha-v3`, but when I want to get the token from the `executeRecaptcha` function, the function always returns null instead of returning the token.

Do you know what's wrong?

Here is the code that I have:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import styles from '../styles/contact.module.css'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { useGoogleReCaptcha } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";

export default function Contact ( ) { 
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState("");

  const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha();

  const handleSumitForm = useCallback(
    async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(executeRecaptcha)
      if (!executeRecaptcha) {
        console.log("Execute recaptcha not yet available");
        return;
      }
      executeRecaptcha("enquiryFormSubmit").then((gReCaptchaToken) => {
        console.log(gReCaptchaToken, "response Google reCaptcha server");
        submitEnquiryForm(gReCaptchaToken);
      });
    },
    [executeRecaptcha, submitEnquiryForm]
  );
  
  
  const submitEnquiryForm = async (gReCaptchaToken) => {
    console.log("form submitted")
    await fetch("/api/contact", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        subject: subject,
        email: email,
        message: message,
        gRecaptchaToken: gReCaptchaToken,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res, "response from backend");
        if (res?.status === "success") {
          setNotification(res?.message);
        } else {
          setNotification(res?.message);
        }
      });
  };
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="Contact">
      <section>
        {notification && <p><strong>{notification}</strong></p>}
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSumitForm}>
            <input className={styles.input} name="subject" placeholder="subject" value={subject} onChange={(e) => setSubject(e?.target?.value)} required/><br/>
            <input className={styles.input} name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e?.target?.value)} required/><br/>
            <textarea className={styles.textarea} name="body" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder='Hi, I wanted to contact you because...' value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e?.target?.value)} required/><br/>
            <input className={styles.submit_button} type="submit" value="Contact"/>
        </form>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

The console always shows:

```
undefined
Execute recaptcha not yet available
```